# deploying same project on same servers different folders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, web, deployment

I have published my MVC project 2 times on server in two different folders

```
1)  \\Servername\DevelopmentStaging

2)  \\ServerName\FinalProduct
```

Actually the need of this was for testing the Project on `DevelopmentStaging`
and then finally publishing to `FinalProduct`

I am using some code in my Web.Config file as::

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Auth/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />

    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />
```

But when I am opening both in same Browser then I have to log in again & again.